# how to do Collections.binarySearch on a collection of byte arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search, comparable

This does not work:

```
List<byte[]> byteArrayList = .... ;
Collections.binarySearch(byteArrayList, new ByteArrayComparator());
```

because byte[] does not extend Comparable. Why isn't it enough that a Comparator is provided?
Any tricks?

Ups, error, i was sure I had the search term inside...

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, you're searching the list of byte arrays for a comparator. It looks like you're calling the wrong binarySearch method, i.e. [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) instead of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Try this:

```
List<byte[]> byteArrayList = .... ;
byte[] valueToFind = .... ;
int index = Collections.binarySearch(byteArrayList,
                                     valueToFind,
                                     new ByteArrayComparator());
```